# How to Color Entire Segmented Bar Plot the Same Color

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, data-visualization

Using the mtcars data:

```
example<-as.matrix(mtcars)
barplot(example)
```

Gives a multi segmented barplot.

[image]
Now I want to make each bar the same color.

So I use:

```
barplot(example,col=c("red","blue"))
```

What I end up with is each segment alternating red and blue.
What I want is the whole bar the same color with each bar a different color.
[image]

Comment: `ggplot` can do this pretty easily, would you be open to a `ggplot` answer?

Comment: If you’ve done a search without duct, then post an example in R code.

Comment: What is duct? Prefer solution in base but open to ggplot. Have not been able to find an answer for this in base so far.

Comment: what are you actually plotting here? What's the y-axis?

Comment: Y axis is "counts" of something

Comment: Plotting a different dataset but using mtcars as an example of what is needed. Currently reverted to using a white graph and colorizing it in mac preview just like the 1970's.

Comment: Y axis do **not** represent counts. It simply stacks the values of `example` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot do that with `barplot`. If you look at the source code of barplot you detect the following relevant lines:

> ```
> for (i in 1L:NC) {
>   xyrect(height[1L:NR, i] + offset[i], w.l[i], 
>          height[-1, i] + offset[i], w.r[i], horizontal = horiz, 
>          angle = angle, density = density, col = col, 
>          border = border)
> [...]
> ```

That is each bar is produced in a loop using the **same** set of colors. So without rewriting barplot you cannot achieve what you want to do.

A `ggplot2` solution would look as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ggplot(mtcars %>% gather(), 
        aes(key, value, fill = key)) +
   geom_col(color = "black")
```

[image: Barplot]

Comment: Any suggestions for removing the looping function in base?

Comment: You could copy the source code and rewrite the code. But I guess that is not really worth the effort as you have an excellent alternative with ggplot.